# Polygon and Lines of the same points are not overlapping correctly

Tags: r, polygon, spacing

I am trying to plot two distributions (`perfectly fair distribution` and `bobbys distribution`) that are binomial variables representing coin flips with a probability of `0.5` and `0.6` respectively. The curves represent the probability of getting a certain # of tails in 100 coin flips.

I am trying to shade in the dashed line curve (`bobbys distribution`) for everything greater than and equal to 60. You can see in my included code that I am using the exact same vectors to call the polygon as I did to call the line.

Why is the polygon and the line offset even though they are made using the exact same numbers?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as actual code, not in image. (Makes it easy to copy-and-paste, also makes it be indexed by the search engine)

Comment: You aren't using the same x-axis values.